# Redshift If TableA contains data then TRUNCATE TableB and INSERT TableA into TableB ELSE do nothing

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, sql-insert, truncate

I am trying to create a query in Redshift but I am struggling to ether create the correct logic or to get it to run full stop.

I have 2 tables `TableA` and `TableB`.

If `TableA` contains data, then wipe `TableB` and insert the data from `TableA`.

Pseudo:

```
CASE WHEN
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TABLEA) > 0
     THEN TRUNCATE TABLEB AND INSERT INTO TABLEB (SELECT * FROM TABLEA)
     ELSE DO NOTHING 
END
```

Obviously this wont work so do I need to do something with an `IF` statement?:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM TABLEA)
    BEGIN
        TRUNCATE TABLE TABLEB
        INSERT INTO TABLEB (SELECT * FROM TABLEA)
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'nothing in table'
    END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a stored procedure. Can't nest queries with side effects inside other queries in a normal SQL query.